# solr scoring during indexing

Tags: solr, spring-data, solrj, solr4

I have a event search engine which stores age range (age-from, age-to) and date range (date-from, date-to).

I want to give higher score for events that are more specific. Less the difference in age range and date range, higher should be the score. i.e. (1) The event with age range 4-5 should have higher score than event with age range 3-6. (2) Event between Oct to Nov should be scored higher than event between Oct to Dec.

I was wondering if it is possible to boost the score during index time or during search. It would be great to boost the score during index time as age range and date range are fixed for a document irrespective of search query.

I use spring data solr in my application to store data into solr.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be boosting at query time using:

```
q={boost b=recip(ms(age_from,age_to),k,1,1)}...
```

`ms` returns date difference in milliseconds [see here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#ms)

`recip(x,m,a,b)` returns `a/(m*x+b)` so is proportional to the inverse of date difference.

I think you have to find a good numeric value for `k`